# Concept of Rain in Islam

Tags: islamic-philosophy

In Islam, why Rain is considered a mercy from God? There are many Hadith/Ayahs where this is explained:

> And We send down from the sky rain chartered with blessing, and We
> produce therewith gardens and grain for harvests. {**Quran 50:9**}
>
> It is Allah who sends the winds, and they stir the clouds and spread
> them in the sky however He wills, and He makes them fragments so you
> see the rain emerge from within them. And when He causes it to fall
> upon whom He wills of His servants, immediately they rejoice **{Quran 30:48}**
>
> O Allah! Let it be a strong fruitful rain. **{Bukhari 1032}**
>
> The people came to the Prophet weeping (due to drought). He said
> (making supplication): O Allah! give us rain which will replenish us,
> abundant, fertilising and profitable, not injurious, granting it now
> without delay. He (the narrator) said: Thereupon the sky became
> overcast. **{Abu Dawud 1169}**
>
> We are given rain by Allah’s mercy, Allah’s providence, and Allah’s
> grace. **{Bukhari}**

and so on

### Question:

Why "Rain" is considered a mercy from God in Islam, why there are Duas/Ayahs/Hadiths for getting "rain" ?? Remember, places where it is always raining, people will consider a sunny day as a huge blessing, so why there are no Duas/Hadith/Ayahs for sunshine?

As Islam began in a desert in 7th century, they had no clue that there are places on earth where it is always raining (like England)... If they knew, they wouldn't have taken rain as a blessing from God... Just like they didn't take 'Sunshine' as a blessing from God as there are no Ayahs/Hadith/Duaa where a supplication for "sunshine" is being depicted ????

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Why "Rain" is considered a mercy from God in Islam, why there are
> Duas/Ayahs/Hadiths for getting "rain" ?? Remember, places where it is
> always raining, people will consider a sunny day as a huge blessing,
> so why there are no Duas/Hadith/Ayahs for sunshine?

Because from water, Seeds can grow, etc there's so many benefits in rain (that i don't think i will type here). We can smell, we have hands etc itself is a blessing and it's not explicitly mentioned in the Qur'an, Doesn't mean it's not a blessing. Anyway, this also happened in the times of Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ)

Narrated Sharik bin `Abdullah bin Abi Namir:

> I heard Anas bin Malik saying, "On a Friday a person entered the main
> Mosque through the gate facing the pulpit while Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)
> was delivering the Khutba. The man stood in front of Allah's Apostle
> and said, 'O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! The livestock are dying and the
> roads are cut off; so please pray to Allah for rain.' " Anas added,
> "Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) (p.b.u.h) raised both his hands and said, 'O
> Allah! Bless us with rain! O Allah! Bless us with rain! O Allah! Bless
> us with rain!' " Anas added, "By Allah, we could not see any trace of
> cloud in the sky and there was no building or a house between us and
> (the mountains of) Sila." Anas added, "A heavy cloud like a shield
> appeared from behind it (i.e. Sila' Mountain). When it came in the
> middle of the sky, it spread and then rained." Anas further said, "By
> Allah! We could not see the sun for a week. Next Friday a person
> entered through the same gate and at that time Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)
> was delivering the Friday's Khutba. The man stood in front of him and
> said, 'O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! The livestock are dying and the roads
> are cut off, please pray to Allah to withhold rain.' " Anas added,
> "Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) I raised both his hands and said, 'O Allah!
> Round about us and not on us. O Allah! On the plateaus, on the
> mountains, on the hills, in the valleys and on the places where trees
> grow.' So the rain stopped and we came out walking in the sun." Sharik
> asked Anas whether it was the same person who had asked for the rain
> (the last Friday). Anas replied that he did not know.

[Bukhari 1013](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:1013)

> As Islam began in a desert in 7th century, they had no clue that there
> are places on earth where it is always raining (like England)... If
> they knew, they wouldn't have taken rain as a blessing from God...
> Just like they didn't take 'Sunshine' as a blessing from God as there
> are no Ayahs/Hadith/Duaa where a supplication for "sunshine" is being
> depicted ????

Rain is a blessing from God , because it has many benefits.  Sun is not only a blessing from God, it's one of the SIGNS of God.

> "And you would have seen the sun, as it rose, inclining away from
> their cave to the right, and as it set, declining away from them to
> the left, while they lay in its open space. That is one of the signs
> of Allah. Whoever Allah guides is truly guided. But whoever He leaves
> to stray, you will never find for them a guiding mentor." (Translation
> by Dr Mustafa Khattab)

Qur'an 18:17

> "We also showed Abraham the wonders of the heavens and the earth, so
> he would be sure in faith. When the night grew dark upon him, he saw a
> star and said, “This is my Lord!” But when it set, he said, “I do not
> love things that set.” Then when he saw the moon rising, he said,
> “This one is my Lord!” But when it disappeared, he said, “If my Lord
> does not guide me, I will certainly be one of the misguided people.”
> Then when he saw the sun shining, he said, “This must be my Lord—it is
> the greatest!” But again when it set, he declared, “O my people! I
> totally reject whatever you associate ˹with Allah in worship˺. I have
> turned my face towards the One Who has originated the heavens and the
> earth—being upright—and I am not one of the polytheists.”"
> (Translation by Dr Mustafa Khattab)

Qur'an 6:74-79

> "Are you ˹O Prophet˺ not aware of the one who argued with Abraham
> about his Lord because Allah had granted him kingship? ˹Remember˺ when
> Abraham said, “My Lord is the One Who has power to give life and cause
> death.” He argued, “I too have the power to give life and cause
> death.” Abraham challenged ˹him˺, “Allah causes the sun to rise from
> the east. So make it rise from the west.” And so the disbeliever was
> dumbstruck. And Allah does not guide the wrongdoing people."
> (Translation by Dr. Mustafa Khattab)

Qur'an 2:258

> "He has ˹also˺ subjected for you the sun and the moon, both constantly
> orbiting, and has subjected the day and night for you. And He has
> granted you all that you asked Him for. If you tried to count Allah’s
> blessings, you would never be able to number them. Indeed humankind is
> truly unfair(Zalim), ˹totally˺ ungrateful." (Translation by Dr.
> Mustafa Khattab

Qur'an 14:33-34

The Qur'an also have a surah named :Ash-Shams (The Sun), Sun is one of the signs of Allah greatness.

And Allah knows best.

Comment: Have u read the question?

Comment: @leth Yes i did. Your question says "Why is Rain is considered a blessing", i answer because Rain has many benefits. Then again your question says "What about the country which is always raining, Sunshine is considered a blessings in that country. WHy there are no hadith on it". Then i answer there is a hadith for it (technically). Then again your questions said "If they knew, they wouldn't consider it a blessing from God", i've answered that they considered both sunshine and Rain as a blessing from God. If i'm wrong, then i apologize and you may elaborate more.